# parse table row with cheerio

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I try to extract some data from a table with cheerio.
Here is a simplified version:

```js
const table = `
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td class="with-link"><a href="www.foo.bar"></a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

`

const row = `<td><a href="www.foo.bar"></a></td>`

class Scraper {
  htmlToDom(html) {
    return cheerio.load(html)
  }
  findHref(row) {
    return row('a').attr('href')
  }
}

const scraper = new Scraper()
const cheerioRow = scraper.htmlToDom(row)
console.log(scraper.findHref(cheerioRow))

const cheerioTable = scraper.htmlToDom(table)
cheerioTable('tr').each(function() {
  //console.log(this)
  let td = this.find('td.with-link')
  console.log(scraper.findHref(td))

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/cheerio@latest"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Scraper class has two methods, one can load the html (string) and returns a cheerio object. The other one expects a (cheerio) td object, and returns  the href from it.

The first console log shows that `findHref` works as expected. Then I load a whole table, loop through its rows (just one in this case). Inside the `each` loop `this` should be a roe (tr) object. I try to find the correct cell (with class 'with-link'), and pass it to `findHref`.

But I am getting

> "TypeError: this.find is not a function

Just in case, here is the JsBin: https://jsbin.com/vakofapiro/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this use cheerioTable.

```
`let td = cheerioTable(this).find('td.with-link').html();`
```

It will give you the inner html of td which is a href

Comment: It maybe works in this example, but what if <a> has text in it. What I want is passing a cheerio td object to scraper's findHref method. This is jut a simplified example. In my app findHref method does much more, and the td also more complicated.